# Is it correct to write "Awaiting to welcome you" in invitation?

Tags: phrases, american-english, politeness, parts-of-speech

I am preparing contents for a wedding card, I have little doubt in writing **Awaiting to welcome you** as the last line of the invitation. Is it okay to write it? or will you please tell me a good line for ending the invitation?

I've also seen some cards with following lines at the end:

```
  Awaiting to welcome you

Mr. Xyz, Relatives & Friends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awaiting to welcome you sounds wrong. If you should use the word "awaiting", then I think, "Awaiting your arrival" sounds better.

Comment: Can I write it as Mr. Xyz, Relatives & Friends are awaiting your arrival?

Comment: Yes. To me it seems like grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

the verb "to await" is followed by a noun or nominal group/phrase and not a non-finite verb. Grammatically, it would be "awaiting your welcome" but this changes the meaning to the other person welcoming you! As such, I recommend changing the phrase. You might try phrases such as

- Please join us for a celebration of love, and friendship, laughter and family
- Bring your dancing shoes. Dinner and music following the ceremony
- A celebration with dinner, drinks and dancing will follow

To express a similar meaning to your original

- we can't wait to see you there

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Personally and from the UK English viewpoint the phrase **Awaiting to welcome you** just sounds wrong.

I would expect to see something more like:

- Hoping that you will attend
- Looking forward to seeing you
- I hope you will be able to come

The most usual last item on a wedding invitation is the letters RSVP from the French répondez s'il vous plaît meaning please reply to let us know if you are attending.